# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{( n^5+2)^{1/4}-(n^2+1)^{1/3}}{(n^4+2)^{1/5}-(n^3+1)^{1/2}}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital, infinity

Evaluate $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\big( n^5+2\big)^{1/4}-\big(n^2+1\big)^{1/3}}{\big(n^4+2\big)^{1/5}-\big(n^3+1\big)^{1/2}}$$

**My Approach:**
I am getting answer as $0$ because effect of denominator is more at $\infty$. But given answer in book is $1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: $0$ is the correct  answer. Your argument is correct.

Comment: Exactly. $\ \frac{3}{2} > \frac{5}{4}.$